# How to get size of a file

Tags: f#

I want to get the size of the files in a directory, but i don't know how to do it.
here is my code:

```
 let givenDirectory="c:/Windows"

 let listOfFilesInDirectory  (givenDirectory:string)=
     let  listOfFiles=Directory.GetFiles  givenDirectory |> List.ofSeq
     let  listOfNames = listOfFiles |> List.map Path.GetFileName
     listOfNames


listOfFilesInDirectory givenDirectory
```

at first i pass a path to the fuction, and i get the full path of every single file in that directory, but i wonder how can i get te size of these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `FileInfo` class:

```
let listOfFilesInDirectory  (givenDirectory:string)=
    let  listOfFiles=Directory.GetFiles  givenDirectory |> List.ofSeq
    listOfFiles |> List.map (fun fn -> 
        Path.GetFileName(fn), FileInfo(fn).Length)
```

Given a file name `fn`, you can create `FileInfo(fn)` and then get the file length using the `Length` property. The above returns a list with file names together with their sizes.

Answer (score 0):

RTFM?

You are using the System.IO namespace. Your reasons for not looking at documentation and then finding the class FileInfo(String)  is ...?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

```
open System.IO

let fileInfo = FileInfo(@"c:\my\file\somewhere.txt") // you may use "c:\\my\\file etc for escape instead of using @ ahead of strings...
let fileLen =  fileInfo.Length
```

This better not be part of some homework\assignment! ;-)